# CachingActivityMapper seems not working

Tags: gwt, caching, android-activity, gwt-mvp

I use MVP pattern for GWT application. I have a filter view and search results view. If the search criteria is modified, search results are getting updated.

But, the selected criteria lost when I refresh the browser. So I want to retain the search criteria and tried using CachingActivityMapper in my onModuleLoad()

```
 CachingActivityMapper cached = new CachingActivityMapper(new AppActivityMapper(clientFactory));
 FilteredActivityMapper.Filter filter = new FilteredActivityMapper.Filter() {
      @Override
      public Place filter(Place place) {
        return place;
      }
    };

 final ActivityManager activityManager = new ActivityManager(activityMapper,
            eventBus);      
 activityManager.setDisplay(filterDisplayView);
```

But I dont see any difference.

Kindly tell what went wrong in my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the docs for [CachingActivityMapper](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/CachingActivityMapper.html) to suggest that it is able to store anything between page reloads. It isn't your code that's wrong here but the assumption that a `CachingActivityMapper` is reload-resilient - it is not. Reloading the page means rebooting your app and loosing all its runtime state, including anything a `CachingActivityMapper` may have cached.

Comment: So, is there a way to add my filters into the URL? So that I can get the runtime filters when the page is refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Look into this for implementing [Local Storage](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage). This could solve your problem.